# trying to transfer a file from my computer to a unix server

Tags: command-line, file-transfer, scp, plink, psftp

I m trying to automate the deployment process wherein i follow the following steps-

1.Run a Ant Script to build a .ear file

2.Login to the unix server using putty(SSH Connection) providing the login credentials.

3.Then i enter the superuser credentials for write permissions.

4.Rename a existing file in the server and then transfer the file from the local system to unix server.

My 1st thought was PSCP or PSFTP,but I have no idea how to provide these super user credentials.

I want a command prompt script so that i can save it as .bat file.Plzz help

Comment: Can you log in if you do `plink Taps@123.123.124.123` (`plink` is the command-line equivalent of `ssh` in the Putty world) and type your password? `pscp` needs a valid username/password to work.

Comment: Are you sure you have write permissions to the file/directory?

Comment: @onix- yes i need to provide the super user credentials to get the permissions.

Comment: @jaume- Yes i can do it using plink...Is it a secure way to connect to the unix server and transfer files??Also i used the script here that should automate the deployment process,but the flow stops whenever it asks for the password.Is there any way to avoid it so that even after entering the password it keep executing the commands from the script.

Answer (score 1):

you can try using WINSCP.

**Please note :** You need to have WinSCP installed in your system and the same can be downloaded from link below:

https://winscp.net/eng/download.php

- Open session using open command.
- For uploads use put command.
- Exit scripting using exit command.

## Commands:

```
#Connect to SFTP server using a password
open sftp://user:password@example.com/ -hostkey="ssh-rsa 2048 xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx..."
#Upload file
put d:\examplefile.txt /home/user/
#Exit WinSCP
exit
```

Refer the link below:

https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_automation

This might help you.

Comment: Thanks, I have updated my comments..hope that explains and help the questioner.